# AIDE Offline Android Repository

Tags: android, repository, aide-ide

How do I put this android repository manually to my AIDE?
I have android repository 47 zip and I don't know how to put it manually.
I'm having trouble with this problem. I hope you'll help me.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included information as to what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I solved my Problem to my AIDE.

- Search .aide folder
- Extract your repository.zip there and be sure it is in the folder
- Go to the AIDE
- To Code section click MORE then click settings
- Go to "Build and Run" section
- Click Local Maven repositories
- put your repository's path (Example: /sdcard/.aide/m2repository)
- Click OK

That'll do the work!